# new column based on existing column

Tags: r

I have a column which contains dates , trying to create a new column which shows the number indicating how many days the dates carry on without any gap .

[image: dates]

as seen in the image the dates range from 2015-01-04 to 2015-01-21 so for 04-01-2015 the new column would say 1 then for 05-01-2015 it would say 2 and for 08-01-2015 it would say 5 , however after that there is a gap of 1 day i.e. there is no 2015-01-10 and the next date is 2015-01-11 so the new column would say 1 again and for 2015-01-12 would say 2 and this would carry on until 15 as we have no gap in dates and for 2015-01-15 it would say 5 this would break again as there is no date for 16 and 17 then fro 2015-01-18 the new column would contain 1 again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be helpful if you have the name of your date column in your question. Not knowing much about your data, here is a solution:

```
# use dplyr -- might have to install it
library(dplyr)

yourdataname %>% 
mutate(FromPreviousDate=as.numeric(difftime(nameofDateCol,lag(nameofDateCol,1))))
```

where `yourdataname` is the name of your data frame and `nameofDateCol` is the column name of the picture you added.

You might need to install `dplyr` to do so run this:

```
install.packages("dplyr")
```

That should work for you.

Comment: Apologies for not providing the name the name of the column is effective_date , it works however instead of saying 1 ,2 ,3 it just says 1 all the way until a gap in dates come in and at each gap it says 3 .

Comment: Really appreciate your assistance